# How to create file of user selected image

Tags: nativescript

I am developing cross platform app with nativescript, I get a problem with getting user selected image from gallery, the library I used return user selected image path. It is very easy in android, it is my code for create File for user selected image that I used in android.

```
String File_Path = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_20171016-173404.png"
File file = new File(File_Path);
```

The reason I need to create File of user selected image is I will need to send user selected image as a File in Multipar/FormData.
I tried many ways can't find soluction. Any suggestion greatly appreciated.

Thanks

It is my sample code for formdata

Answer (score 0):

Use nativescript background http, pass the path to this function

```
viewModel.uploadImage = function (imageUrl) {
        var token = applicationSettings.getString("accessToken");
        var form = new FormData();
        form.append("file", imageUrl);

        var bghttp = require("nativescript-background-http");

        var session = bghttp.session("image-upload");

        var request = {
            url: <url>,
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
                "File-Name": "somename",
                "Authorization": token
            },
            description: "image for something"
        };

        var params = [
                    { name: "somename", value: "value" },
                    { name: "fileToUpload", filename: imageUrl, mimeType: 'image/jpeg' }
                ];
        let task = session.multipartUpload(params, request);
        return task;     
    }
```

Comment: How to handle the returned task can be seen here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-background-http

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works, however another option would be to convert the selected image to a `Base64String` and treat it as any other string.

To do that just create a new `ImageSource` from file path and than simply use the `toBase64String` method provided.
Simlpy pass the format (jpg, png etc) and you're all set